# Перевод с Gradle на Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, gradle

Передо мной оказалась такая задача: перевести работающий проект с gradle на maven (ну так уж захотелось заказчику). 
У меня с этим возникли определенные трудности. Я думал, что вся работа сведется к удалению файлов и папок gradle и добавлением вместо всего этого pom.xml, а дальше идея все доделает. Однако, я напоролся на вилы)

Прошу помочь мне с этим делом.

Если принять, что pom.xml написан правильно, мне нужен порядок действий:

- как правильно удалить gradle, чтобы идея про него забыла
- как дать понять идее, что теперь надо работать с maven через pom.xml
- если нужно сгенерить какие-то файлы, то как

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Удалить gradle, закрыть проект, после чего удалить папку **.idea**.  Папка с таким названием должна лежать корне проекта, и в ней содержатся настройке среды разработки для конкретного проекта.

2) Повторно импортировать проект, выбрать файл pom.xml при импорте, дальше среда разработки сама предложит импортировать как maven проект.

3) Я так понял, для того чтобы сгенерировать какие-то файлы, будет необходимо собрать проект. Собирается maven командой : **mvn clean install**

Comment: а градловчкий файлик глянуть можно? что там вообще подключено?

Comment: можно, для этого я бы создал две копии проекта, одну с gradle, а другую с удаленным gradle и минимально заполненным pom.xml. Импортировал бы обе копии в проект и переписывал бы.

Но если это вопрос мне был задан, допускаю, что вопрос был к автору вопроса.